# Loading One to Many associated attribute with SQLalchemy and Marshmallow

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, python-3.4, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a flask api and I am trying to learn how to load a parent model's attribute from a 1-n relationship.

First I load all Inventory items. This works great. My goal is to load each inventory items', parent model (Material) name attribute.

Just to clear things up a Material has many Inventory items. An inventory item belongs to a material. And I have a collection of all inventory items.

My goal is something like this:

```
{'id': 1, 'location': None, 'material_name': {'name': 'load name'}
```

But I am never loading the name, it returns blank:

```
{'id': 1, 'location': None, 'material_name': {'name': ''}
```

I'm using Marshmallow to create a flask-api and return nice JSON.

here is my model.py

```
from app import db
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class Material(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=False)
    items = db.relationship('Inventory', backref='material', lazy='dynamic')

class Inventory(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    location = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=False)
    material_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('material.id'))
    def __init__(self, material_name):
        self.material_name = material_name

##### SCHEMAS (marshmallow) #####
# http://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html

class MaterialSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    name = fields.Str()

class InventorySchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    location = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    material_name = fields.Nested(MaterialSchema, only=["name"])
```

and my query:

```
inventory_schema = InventorySchema(many=True)
@api.route('/api/inventory', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def inventoryindex():
    d=request.args['q']
    if len(d) >= 1:
        search_term = "%{0}%".format(d)
        count = Inventory.query.filter(Inventory.location.like(search_term)).count
        items = Inventory.query.filter(Inventory.location.like(search_term)).limit(10)
    else:
        count = Inventory.query.count()
        items = Inventory.query.limit(10)
    result = inventory_schema.dump(items)
    print(result)
    dictionary = {}
    for obj in result[0]:
        dictionary[obj['id']] = obj
    return jsonify({'dict':dictionary})
```

It returns everything I expect, except the material name is empty. How can I load the material id, from the inventory query above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution 1

Why do you want to have it like this at the first place. `item['material_name']['name']` looks like duplication of the `name` twice.

IMO the best solution is to change format to:

```
{'id': 1, 'location': None, 'material': {'name': 'load name'}
```

Than you can change your schema to get material name loaded:

```
class InventorySchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    location = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    material = fields.Nested(MaterialSchema, only=["name"])
```

#### Solution 2

If you insist on having asked format, you can change `InventorySchema` to take value from the correct attribute by passing `attribute` argument:

```
class InventorySchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    location = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    material_name = fields.Nested(MaterialSchema, attribute='material', only=["name"])
```

Comment: Will this trigger N+1 queries to fetch the material names?

Comment: @pate I'm not familiar with Marshmallow internals, but most likely yes. To fix this you can override the query to include something like `.options(joinedload="material")`.